# Will a donation app with PayPal mobile sdk apply to Apple guidelines?

Tags: ios, paypal, donations

I am developing an iOS app that basically allow people to donate money to charities. This app will be free on the App Store.
Apple guidelines state the following:

> 21.Charities and contributions
>
> 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
>
> 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

i want to use PayPal mobile sdk (MPL library) to charge the user and pass the money between his PayPal account and the charity's PayPal account.

Is this comply with apple rules (especially 21.2)? will my app be rejected by apple?
must i use a web-view in my app for the implementation of the payment stage? is PayPal mobile sdk apply to their rules?

Comment: Apple ultimately has the right to accept or reject any app they choose. You may want to try to go to the Apple forums on this. Perhaps someone from Apple can comment on it. Anything on SO would just be a opinion. Wether someone has experienced it or not is irrelevant because they can choose to accept yours and reject the next guys.

Comment: Kara, thanks for your reply. I also posted it on Apple's forums and got no response.